# Using memcpy to change a jnz to a jmp

Tags: memcpy

Not used memcpy much but here's my code that doesn't work.

```
memcpy((PVOID)(enginebase+0x74C9D),(void *)0xEB,2);
```

(enginebase+0x74C9D) is a pointer location to the address of the bytes that I want to patch.

(void *)0xEB is the op code for the kind of jmp that I want.

Only problem is that this crashes the instant that the line tries to run, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any incite?

Comment: There is a strong possibility executable memory is write-protected.

Comment: zneak: Isn't that even a guarantee nowadays?

Comment: Wow, that's something I didn't even think of, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

The argument `(void*)0xEB` is saying to copy memory from address `0xEB`; presumably you want something more like

```
unsigned char x = 0xEB;
memcpy((void*)(enginebase+0x74c9d), (void*)&x, 2);
```

in order to properly copy the *value* 0xEB to the destination.  BTW, is 2 the right value to copy a single byte to program memory?  Looks like it should be 1, since you're copying 1 byte.  I'm also under the assumption that you can't just do

```
((char*)enginebase)[0x74c9d] = 0xEB;
```

for some reason?  (I don't have any experience overwriting program memory intentionally)

Answer (score 0):

**memcpy()** expect two pointers for the source and destination buffers. Your second argument is not a pointer but rather the data itself (it is the opcode of **jnz**, as you described it). If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you should set an array with the opcode as its contetns, and provide **memcpy()** with the pointer to that array.

The program crashes b/c you try to reference a memory location out of your assigned space (address 0xEB).